# MySQL - Add values to the IN clause?

Tags: mysql, union

I am currently have this query:

```
SET sql_mode='';
SELECT `id`, `url`,`number`,`abbrev`,`content`,`label`,`hier-1` FROM `leganalyse_unitsub_2020` WHERE `id` IN  (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `leganalyse_unitsub_2020` GROUP BY `url`)
```

The subquery in the following clause:

```
SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `leganalyse_unitsub_2020` GROUP BY `url`
```

returns a set of integer values.

For each integer value returned x, I'd like to also include x-1, x-2, x-3, x-4 and x-5.

So something like:

```
SELECT `id`, `url`,`number`,`abbrev`,`content`,`label`,`hier-1` FROM `leganalyse_unitsub_2020` WHERE `id` IN  
(
SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `leganalyse_unitsub_2020` GROUP BY `url`
UNION
SELECT MAX(`id`)-1 FROM `leganalyse_unitsub_2020` GROUP BY `url`
UNION
SELECT MAX(`id`)-2 FROM `leganalyse_unitsub_2020` GROUP BY `url`
UNION
SELECT MAX(`id`)-3 FROM `leganalyse_unitsub_2020` GROUP BY `url`
UNION
SELECT MAX(`id`)-4 FROM `leganalyse_unitsub_2020` GROUP BY `url`
)
```

But I am not sure if this is correct.

What query will do what I have described?

Answer (score 0):

Cross join the subquery with a query that returns 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 to get all the possible values:

```
SELECT id, url,number, abbrev, content, label, hier-1 
FROM leganalyse_unitsub_2020 WHERE id IN (
  SELECT g.id - t.id
  FROM (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) id FROM leganalyse_unitsub_2020 GROUP BY url) g
)
```

This code is based on your last query. 
If you want the values to be like x-1, x-2, x-3, x-4 and x-5 as you mention in the question the you should use this subquery:

```
SELECT 1 id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5
```